Getting 404 while deploying Express app made with typescript
I am trying to deploy an express app made with typescript to vercel. But no matter how hard I try I am getting 404.

I have configured my tsconfig.json file in a way, so that When I run npm run build locally, it creates a dist folder in the root. In package.json file I have set the start command to node dist/index.js. After building the file locally, when I try npm start, it works fine. But the problem is when I deploy it to vercel it doesn't work. This is my vercel.json file:
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "dist/index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/dist/index.js"
    }
  ]
}

In the vercel dashboard I have set the output directory to dist. Here is the screenshot.

I have tried several changes in the vercel.json file, like changing the src and dest properties. But none worked.
